# What does the ‘globalNamespaces’ option in the ‘unplugin vue components’ plugin mean?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vite, vite-plugin-development

Office Doc:

```js
  // Allow subdirectories as namespace prefix for components.
  directoryAsNamespace: false,

  // Collapse same prefixes (camel-sensitive) of folders and components
  // to prevent duplication inside namespaced component name.
  // works when `directoryAsNamespace: true`
  collapseSamePrefixes: false,

  // Subdirectory paths for ignoring namespace prefixes.
  // works when `directoryAsNamespace: true`
  globalNamespaces: [],
```

But I still don't understand the globalNamespaces option, Can you give me an example? Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe this [pr](https://github.com/unplugin/unplugin-vue-components/pull/8) will help you.

Comment: @init-qy thank you